# PayPal phone number not shown (using PP php sdk)

Tags: php, paypal

We have the following code to transfer our buyer's details to the PayPal:

```
$ShippingAddr = new AddressType;
// more code ...
$ShippingAddr->Phone = $_userdata['user_phone'];

$BillingAddr = new AddressType;
// more code ...
$BillingAddr->Phone = $_userdata['user_phone'];

$setECReqDetails = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType();
// more code ...
$setECReqDetails->Address = $ShippingAddr;
$setECReqDetails->BillingAddress = $BillingAddr;

$setECReqType = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestType();
$setECReqType->Version = '104.0';
$setECReqType->SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails = $setECReqDetails;

$setECReq = new SetExpressCheckoutReq();
$setECReq->SetExpressCheckoutRequest = $setECReqType;
$setECResponse = $paypalService->SetExpressCheckout($setECReq);
```

Working fine apart from the phone number which remains empty on PayPal checkout site.
Any idea what we did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to get users information as per this webservice. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#get-user-information

So you should call it this way according to the paypal doc,

```
$_userdata['phone_number'];
```

Comment: $_userdata is an associative string array, containing all the collected customer's details (on a previous form), not the part of the PayPal's response. I don't think different keyname would solve this problem :)

Comment: Can you please post the code where you get the users information ? that is where the issue should be.